# Source for "the land of Israel makes its inhabitants wise"

Tags: quotations

I would like to know the source of the quotation: "Eretz yisrael m'chakim es yoshvehah"? My translation: The land of Israel makes its inhabitants wise.

Comment: Helpful also (in Hebrew): https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=4660

Answer (score 8):

From Masechet Bava Batra, 158b

> בחזקת מי ר' אילא אמר בחזקת יורשי האם ר' זירא אמר בחזקת יורשי הבן כי סליק רבי זירא קם בשיטתיה דרבי אילא קם רבה בשיטתיה דרבי זירא אמר רבי זירא שמע מינה אוירא דארץ ישראל מחכים
>
> The mishna states that according to Rabbi Akiva, the property retains its previous ownership status. The Gemara asks: In whose possession does the property remain? Rabbi Ila says: It remains in the possession of the mother’s heirs. Rabbi Zeira, when he was still in Babylonia, said: It remains in the possession of the son’s heirs. When Rabbi Zeira ascended to Eretz Yisrael, he adopted the opinion of Rabbi Ila, whereas Rabba, in Babylonia, adopted the opinion stated by Rabbi Zeira. Rabbi Zeira said: Conclude from this incident that **the air of Eretz Yisrael makes one wise**

From sefaria (including the explanation between the words).

Extending this, the Ohr Hachaim on Vayikra 19:23 writes

> אוירה של ארץ ישראל מחכים ומטהר הנפש
>
> The air of the land of Israel makes the soul wise and pure.